# Which engine does the stock Samsung Browser use?

Tags: samsung-internet-browser

Which engine does the stock Samsung Browser use? Is it based on WebKit, Gecko, or something else?

Comment: Webkit is de-facto engine in AOSP, having said that, Google are keen to drop webkit soon enough now that Blink is 1 year old...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android default browser uses WebKit.
Check out the second paragraph of [Wikipedia WebKit description](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=WebKit&oldid=603213415).

Answer (score 2):

After reviewing some user-agent strings, all native Samsung browsers I saw use WebKit.

There are particular idiosyncrasies when working with this family browser amongst devices, and a lot of weird behavior. According to [*What browser does the Samsung Galaxy use?* on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19551809/489396), there is some "value-added" by Samsung to the AOSP browser.

Answer (score 0):

It is based on Chromium, it uses Blink (WebKit fork).
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Internet